# Can graphviz create automatic group/cluster outlines?

Tags: graphviz

I am creating a network graph from some data. Not all the data is connected, leading to individual groups (or clusters? I'm not sure of the right terminology).

Below is an example of what it looks like. (I was using 'neato' here).

Is it possible to get graphviz to detect and draw lines around the individual groups?

I have looked at a number of dot examples with subgraphs. However, that would require me to know up-front which nodes belong in the same group, which means I would have to traverse each node to find all the connected nodes so I can include them in respective subgraphs.

I was hoping the framework can somehow do this for me automatically.

[image]

Comment: Please show the, dot, code you used to draw the image. I think you might want to look into the `subgraph` (and get some inspiration at e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54769287/graphviz-dotted-box-around-same-grouped-boxes)

Comment: @albert Thanks, I have looked at a number of dot examples with subgraphs. However, that would require me to know up-front which nodes belong in the same group, which means I would have to traverse each node to find all the connected nodes so I can include them in respective subgraphs. I was hoping the framework can somehow do this for me automatically. Sorry, I will update my question to make this clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that **ccomps** (http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/ccomps.1.pdf) (a Graphviz program) can identify disconnected subsets and create a subgraph for each subset.  The following (Linux) command will identify these subsets and create a cluster around each.
`ccomps -x myfile.gv | sed -e '/digraph .*_cc_/s/digraph /subgraph cluster/' -e '1idigraph N {' -e '$a}'`

Comment: Whoops, on second look **ccomps** does not do exactly what I expected.  Back to drawing board.

Comment: ccomps solution was fixed